# Leaking std::shared_ptr thread_local variable in C++ - C++/CLI environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, web-services, wcf, c++-cli

So I have this WCF webservice server where one of my webservices is written in C++/CLI. The webservice method is only a stub. It is used to call native C++ useful code.

In the useful C++ code, I have this thread_local std::shared_ptr variable. It is allocated in a method called by the web service.

```
thread_local std::shared_ptr<MyClass> leaking(new MyClass());
```

The problem is: my variable is never deallocated. The destructor is never called. 
I am compiling my code using Microsoft C++ 14.0 64-bit compiler.

**My question is : Is there some weird limitation with thread_local support and the Microsoft compiler ?**

I couldn't find anything on MSDN.

**What I have tried :**

I know WCF uses a .NET thread pool to handle web service requests.I read somewhere that a .Net thread is not guaranteed to be mapped to the same native thread during its lifetime. However, in the  current implementation, .Net threads *are* mapped 1 to 1 to the same native thread.

I tried enumerating the active threads right before process exit and only the process main thread was active.

**Edit:**

I just found this on MSDN:

> Automatic data objects cannot be declared with the thread attribute.

[Link to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yh4a9k1.aspx)

However this seems to apply only to Microsoft's 'thread' modifier. Compilation does show the documented error with 'thread' but not with 'thread_local' so I guess this does not solve my problem.

Comment: What is the scope of leaking ? global ? Is it ever assigned something else, like null? Is the thread killed without the shared_ptr being assigned something else?

Comment: Yes it is leaking globally. It is only assigned once: At initialisation. i don't manually kill the thread as it is managed by WCF. I would be suprised if WCF killed the thread but it is defnitely something I can check !

Comment: Having a `thread_local shared_ptr<>` in a simple console app makes the program crash instantly.

The thread_local variable is in a method `void Run()` in a static c++ library. A C++/CLI console program links against this static library and calls `Run()`.

A reproducable example would be nice.

Comment: As said earlier the c++/cli part is only a stub. It calls a function defined in a a native dll (compiled without /clr) which allocates the thread_local variable

Comment: Here is a simple project to reproduce the problem https://github.com/elmadj/LeakingServer.git After building the project, you just need to start the WCFServer application call the two methods of the service (DoWork and StopServer)

Answer (score 2):

> **6.7.2 Thread storage duration.**
>
> All variables declared with the **thread_local** keyword have *thread storage duration*. The storage for these entities shall last for the duration of the thread in which they are created. There is a distinct object or reference per thread, an use  of the declared name refers to the entity associated with the current thread.
>
> A variable with the **storage duration** shall be initialized before its first odr-use (6.2) and, if constructed, shall be destroyed on thread exit.

Comment: I assume WCF does not kill the thread at all. Most probably it allocates a thread pool and calls your thread function in a thread from a pool.

Comment: @elmadj I have quoted the most modern draft 4659 that I have. 3.7.2 was from the older draft 3337.

Comment: As I said in my question I enumerate the process threads right before exit. Only the mainthread remains.

Comment: :) sorry I didn't check the version on the draft I used !

Answer (score 1):

A shared_ptr is not a magic bullet. It will only delete its content when it is assigned something else. From your comments, it seems you keep it forever, once assigned. As such, it will not delete the object, by design.

The scenario I imagine is the same as:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Foo
{
public:
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Deleted" << std::endl;}
};

thread_local std::shared_ptr<Foo> f;

void t()
{
    f = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo);
}

int main()
{
    std::thread thread(t);
    thread.detach();
}
```

Comment: Well the object held by a std::shared_ptr is also destroyed when the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is destroyed. 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr.

thread_local variables should go out of scope and be destroyed when the thread ends so why is my std:shared_ptr not destroyed ?

Comment: Depends how cleanly the thread ends. See edit for reproducing something similar in non-MS specific C++11

Comment: The thread seems to exit normally (exit code 0). I checked by tracing the native thread id right after the variable is allocated. and comparing it to the debugger's output which shows the exit codes for all threads

Comment: we tried compiling your code. It does not leak. This beahviour is expected since the documentation for thread::detach says : "Separates the thread of execution from the thread object, allowing execution to continue independently. Any allocated resources will be freed once the thread exits. "